# TalkBack: Prevent Selection of Obscured View

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

[image: Bad TalkBack Image]

In the image above, you can see that TalkBack has selected a label that is completely obscured.  If I tap again, then the entire panel at the top will be selected (it's set as focusable) which is the desired behavior.

How can I prevent TalkBack from selecting complete (or partially) obscured views for announcement?

At a minimum, how can I force talkback to select the top/obscuring view FIRST?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the code below, So TalkBack will ignore that view/image:

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

**Updated Answer:**

When the View is obscured set it to the root of the obscured this:

```
mainContentView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

Then when you bring that view back do this:

```
mainContentView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

Comment: This would disable it permanently.  The panel/view at the top is sometimes visible, sometimes not.  I want to disable the obscured view, but *only* when it is obscured.  Add to that that this is in an SDK, so I don't actually know what views may or may not be obscured, as they belong to the user of my SDK, not me.

Comment: hey @DavidBerry did you by any chance solve this in any way? I am facing the same issue and run out of options what to do about it

Comment: @rgreso not really.  Wish I had a better answer still.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's not quite enough information to answer this completely.  It's not clear whether your "Learn" more thing is a modal dialog, and so needs dealt with, or if it can remain on screen and interaction with the things lower in the layout should remain accessible.

Scenario 1: Let's assume that the "Learn More" dialog is a modal that should be dealt with before everything else, what you want is to use a custom AlertDialog. The Android system will then set up all of the important properties, without requiring different permissions. Ultimately what the Android OS does in this case is add a new view with TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, which ensures that the dialog is the only actionable thing on screen (and also only accessible!).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Scenario 2: The "Learn More" banner is not a modal.  What you want to do is hide the view behind the banner. You can do this by setting `view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);`.

Comment: Scenario 2, it's more of a banner, not a modal.  The views NOT obscured must still be usable.  I take it I should use setImportantForAccessibility on the obscured views?  I'm not sure that actually works as partially obscured views should also still be accessible, just not

Comment: You could also fix this by making the entire banner a touch target (accessibility focusable), which actually fairly accurately reflects what's happening. Then add an accessibility delegate, and scroll down when a user uses gesture navigation to focus the obscured control. That's kind of complicated to code up, but if you approve of that solution, I'll give you a prototype version.

Comment: Yes, it is scrollable (at least in this case)  What's going on here is I provide an toolkit, which, among other things presents a banner over whatever content the underlying application is currently presenting.  Any portion of the screen that's not currently obscured, should continue to allow all normal interaction.  The long discussion is mostly to emphasize that I don't control, or wish to interfere with, the content behind the banner.

Comment: I think I tried setting the entire view as focusable, but it still didn't prevent accessibility touches from going through to the underlying view.

Comment: How is this banner implemented? Are these views that end up in the application's layout?  Or is this view an overlay of some kind?

Comment: Right now the SDK manually adds it to the activity's content view (`activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)`)

Comment: I don't suppose this library is open source or available? Or you have an example somewhere? I have a few ideas about how to mark this up, but I want to play with it on my own before I post an answer. This is more of an accessibility question, than a development question. There are a lot of different API options, but picking the right one for the myriad of Assistive Technologies (TalkBack, BrailleBack, Switch access, Eye Tracking) that this effects is important, so I want to get it right. Plus I feel like this is not a question that has been asked before, but I see devs do this poorly a lot! :)

Comment: It's not, but let me see what I can work up as far as a minimum reproducible case is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Layout Inspector to find this label and remove its visibility.

Per Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)
    To open the Layout Inspector, do the following:

1. Run your app on a connected device or emulator.
2. Click Tools > Layout Inspector.
3. In the Choose Process dialog that appears, select the app process you want to inspect and click OK.
4. The Layout Inspector captures a snapshot, saves it as a .li file, and opens it.

Set the visibility to GONE, programmatically or in the layout file:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Or

```
nameOfLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: This isn't really a workable solution for two reasons, the biggest of which is that I don't own/control the underlying views, just the overlay.